# Why Google play services not included in Doze mode

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, battery, battery-life, google-play-services, doze-mode

I'm using Nexus 5 and 6P, Android 6 having a feature called "Battery optimization mode" or Doze mode (in short). It is allowing apps not to run, if they aren't used to avoid battery consumption.

Google play services consumes more battery, RAM and CPU. But it is not included in Doze mode.

I've sent multiple feedback from my devices about this issue, but Google is not hearing at all.

Anyone please help me clarify, Why Google play services not included in Doze mode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google Play services is excluded because Google wants it so. It has to remained excluded from Doze or any power saving mode because apps depending upon [Google Cloud Messaging](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/gcm#arch) (GCM) may fail to serve the user appropriately, hence, ruining the user's experience with Android big time. A [GCM Android Client](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client) requires Play Store and Play services installed in Android device.

Anyhow, here's the brief reason: in the file `/system/etc/sysconfig/google.xml`, other than the usage policy of the file it is noted:

```
<!-- These are configurations that must exist on all GMS devices. -->
<config>
    <!-- These are the standard packages that are white-listed to always have internet
         access while in power save mode, even if they aren't in the foreground. -->

    <!-- GmsCore must always have network access for GCM and other things. -->
    <allow-in-power-save package="com.google.android.gms" />

    <!-- Play Store likewise must have network access to support other applications. -->
    <allow-in-power-save-except-idle package="com.android.vending" />
```

where,

- *com.google.android.gms* : package name of Google Play services
- *com.android.vending*: package name of Google Play Store

I cannot precisely speak of what counts as *other things*. My educated guess is the APIs made available through Play Services. Refer to *Table 1.* [here](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#add_google_play_services_to_your_project) to see the list of those APIs.

**Note**: it is beyond the scope of this answer or the question itself why Google decided to keep Play Services and Store always excluded from power saving features of Android instead of finding and implementing a hybrid path.

Comment: Excellent explanation. Thanks. If google don't want to add it doze, least they can do for users will be, try to optimize the battery consumed by Play services. is n't it?

Comment: Yes, that is true but until Google does that, perhaps my question could help you out: [How to make Google Play services and other default white-listed system apps Doze?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/143247/96277)

Answer (score 2):

This is one reason, there may be more

[Google Play Services](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Play_Services) has location API. And your Android Device Manager (ADM) which you use to track your stolen or misplaced device uses location API. Let's say you forgot your phone leaving for home and on reaching home want to locate your phone by logging into ADM

You can do that successfully only if your ADM (using location API) is not affected by *doze*, which is the case as cited here [Does Doze interfere with Android Device Manager?](http://m.androidcentral.com/forums-does-doze-interfere-android-device-manager). If *doze* affected Play Services, then you won't be able to track your phone at all

Comment: Thanks. Planning to disable ADM for a day, to confirm any change in battery life.

Comment: More than ADM, auto back of apps/ games/data by Google Play would consume more battery. Suggest disable that and see

Comment: Turning off ADM has improved battery life by extra one hour. SOT 4hrs 15mins with full use of WiFi and Clash of clans for an hour, battery dipped from 100% to 10%.

Comment: Thanks for sharing that useful information :) all the best

Answer (score 2):

Google Play Services is in charge of Google Cloud Messaging (GCM). [GCM is the mechanism by which applications can request to exit doze mode](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html#using_gcm), upon receiving [*high priority* messages](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/concept-options) from GCM. In other words, Google Play Services is partly in control of doze mode, so it cannot be dozed.